# How to define own doxygen comment styles?

Tags: comments, customization, doxygen

I would like to know whether it is possible to define own doxygen comment styles. The usual style is something like this (Javadoc-like):

```
/**
*
*   Descriptions and stuff
*
*/
```

or (when using Qt):

```
/*!
*
*   Descriptions and stuff
*
*/
```

I would prefer something like

```
/*!===============================================================
*
*   Descriptions and stuff
*
================================================================*/
```

But the doxygen parser doesn't allow this syntax. So my questions is, if there is a way to **define own comment styles**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can define your own comment styles, but with some slight changes to the format, it might match.

See this page on [documentation blocks](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) in the Doxygen documentation:

Some people like to make their comment blocks more visible in the documentation. For this purpose you can use the following:

```
/********************************************//**
 *  ... text
 ***********************************************/
```

(note the 2 slashes to end the normal comment block and start a special comment block).

or

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// ... text ...
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Yep, I already tried the first one and find it quite good cause it's kinda pleasing to the eye.. More than the second example IMHO. I just thought there might be a way to customize the style, thanks anyways :)